# Get exact colorization color

Tags: vb.net, windows

I would like to know if there's a way to get the **exact** color of Windows 8 windows (the color displayed in title bar). I've found many forum threads relating to this, but they all refer to a registry key (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM\ColorizationColor) or to an external library (dwmapi.dll), and they both return a different color.

[image]

Comment: That is not the colorization color.  Use, say, Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.ActiveCaption)

Comment: Hans, I would like to get the color of the caption bar (in the case of my image, something similar to purple). But this color changed depending on the user (for example, if the user selects red, I would like to get red). Thank you.

Comment: Of course.  The only possible mistake you can make is not actually trying it.

Answer (score 0):

It could be one of the "system colors".

Have you tried for instance:

```
SystemColors.InactiveCaption
SystemColors.ActiveCaption
SystemColors.GradientInactiveCaption
SystemColors.GradientActiveCaption
```

(there are also other ones which can be tried:
cf: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.SystemColors_properties(v=vs.110).aspx

PS.

In RGB terms, the color you show should be (in case adjust the alpha value):

```
Color.FromArgb(255, 117, 125, 187)
```

Comment: Hi pam, SystemColors are the same for all computers. The "ActiveCaption" color will be the same also if the user has set a different color.

Comment: Do you mean that if the user changed colors, you still want the "original" (win default before any user style change) color? If so the question is even simpler. You can just use color.fromargb() plugging those RGB components (you can immediately get them with photoshop for instance)

Comment: @superPanda I added those RGB components, just in case may be useful

Comment: Thanks Pam for your replies. I don't mean this: I would like to get the color that the user chose for windows.

Comment: Hmm, I may be missing what is your issue @superPanda and what you mean by "color will be the same also if the user has set a different color", but as far as I know that is the purpose of using SystemColors instead of "fixed" colors. In fact we also have the handler: Private Sub Form1_SystemColorsChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.SystemColorsChanged

Comment: Hi, if you're using Windows 8 you surely know that the user can choose a customized color for windows title bar. And you probably know that this color is stored on the registry but if we try to get it, it will return a color darker than the original user-chosen color. Sorry if I was not clear, hope you can now understand. Thanks

Comment: @superPanda I don't have win 8. However I was assuming that if you change the colors for windows title bar (or any other system color), that change should be reflected in the SystemColors enumeration, or else there would be no much point in having such enumeration. But I may be missing something. Cf: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms906614.aspx. The darker/lighter version might be the active/inactive versions.

Answer (score -2):

Finally found a work-around for this problem.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Form1
   <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
   Public Structure MARGINS
       Public Destra As Integer
       Public Sinistra As Integer
       Public Su As Integer
       Public Giu As Integer
   End Structure
Declare Auto Function DwmIsCompositionEnabled Lib "dwmapi.dll" Alias "DwmIsCompositionEnabled" (ByRef pfEnabled As Boolean) As Integer
Declare Auto Function DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea Lib "dwmapi.dll" Alias "DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef pMargin As Margins) As Integer
Dim pMargins As New Margins With {.Su = -1, .Sinistra = -1, .Destra = -1, .Giu = -1}
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim en As Boolean = False
    DwmIsCompositionEnabled(en)
    If en Then
        DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(Me.Handle, pMargins)
    End If
    Me.TransparencyKey = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.ActiveCaption)
    Me.BackColor = Me.TransparencyKey
End Sub
End Class
```

(taken from http://gabriele97.wordpress.com/creare-una-finestra-aero-in-vb-net/)

This extends title bar's color to all the form and, so, makes the form's background the same as the Windows color.

I'm just wondering why is it so difficult to read the exact colorization color from the registry...

Thanks anyway, @Pam and @HansPassant !